# Zend_Cache with memcached and multiple instances

Tags: zend-framework, memcached, zend-cache

I'm trying to get Zend_Cache to work with two different instances of memcached. Both instances are active and listening, I tested this, yet Zend_Cache keeps on cramming everything in the default port of memcached, totally disregarding the second instance. This is my code in my bootstrap:

```
    $backend = array(
        'name' => 'Memcached',
        'servers' => array( array(
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '11211'
        ) ),
        'compression' => true
    );

    $backend_system = array(
        'name' => 'Memcached',
        'servers' => array( array(
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '11212'
        ) ),
        'compression' => true
    );   

    $systemCache = array(
            'frontend' => array(
                'name' => 'Core',
                'options' => array(
                    'lifetime' => 7*24*60*60,
                    'automatic_serialization' => true
                )
            ),
            'backend' => $backend_system
        );            

    $dataCache = array(
            'frontend' => array(
                'name' => 'Core',
                'options' => array(
                    'lifetime' => 1*60*60,
                    'automatic_serialization' => true
                )
            ),
            'backend' => $backend
        );

    $manager = new Zend_Cache_Manager;
    $manager->setCacheTemplate('system', $systemCache);
    $manager->setCacheTemplate('data', $dataCache);
    Zend_Registry::set( 'manager' , $manager );
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer was a simple one: I forgot to enclose my options in an array in the $backend* arrays, like this:

```
    $backend_system = array(
        'name' => 'Memcached',
        'options' => array(
            'servers' => array( array(
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => '11212'
            ) ),
            'compression' => true
        )
    );
```